# How to speed up a query?

Tags: mysql

```
select
dt.total_paket,dt.total_paket_selesai,dt.total_pagu,dt.pagu_selesai,dt.penawaran,dt.selisih,dt.selisih_persen,
thn.tahun as tahun_lelang
from (select  TO_CHAR((current_date - interval '1 year' * a),'YYYY') AS tahun FROM generate_series(0,4,1) AS s(a)) thn
LEFT JOIN
(select
    count(semualelang)                      as total_paket,
    count(selesailelang)                        as total_paket_selesai,
    sum(semualelang.pkt_pagu)                   as total_pagu,
    sum(selesailelang.pagu_selesai)                 as pagu_selesai,
    sum(selesailelang.penawaran)                    as penawaran,
    sum(selesailelang.pagu_selesai) - sum(selesailelang.penawaran)  as selisih,
    round((sum(selesailelang.pagu_selesai) - sum(selesailelang.penawaran)) / sum(selesailelang.pagu_selesai)  * 100::numeric)   AS selisih_persen,
    date_part('YEAR', semualelang.lls_tgl_setuju)                   as tahun_lelang
from(
select agen.agc_nama,sk.stk_id,sk.stk_nama,ls.lls_id,ls.pkt_id,sd.sbd_id,sd.sbd_ket,a.ang_tahun,p.pkt_nama,p.pkt_pagu,p.pkt_hps,p.kgr_id,ls.mtd_pemilihan,ls.lls_tgl_setuju from lelang_seleksi ls 
        left join paket p on ls.pkt_id=p.pkt_id
        left join (select pa.pkt_id,pa.ang_id from paket_anggaran pa inner join (select pkt_id,max(auditupdate) as auditupdate from paket_anggaran group by pkt_id) pa1 on pa1.pkt_id=pa.pkt_id and pa1.auditupdate=pa.auditupdate) pa on pa.pkt_id=p.pkt_id
        left join satuan_kerja sk on p.stk_id=sk.stk_id
        left join agency agen on agen.agc_id=sk.agc_id
        left join anggaran a on pa.ang_id=a.ang_id
        left join sumber_dana sd on a.sbd_id=sd.sbd_id
        where ls.lls_status=1) semualelang 
                                            left join (
                                            select e.lls_id,n.psr_id,pemenang.pagu_selesai,pemenang.nev_harga,min(n.nev_harga) as penawaran,pemenang.eva_jenis from evaluasi e inner join nilai_evaluasi n on e.eva_id=n.eva_id 
                                                inner join (select n.psr_id,e.eva_id,ls.lls_id, p.pkt_pagu as pagu_selesai, n.nev_harga,e.eva_jenis from lelang_seleksi ls
                                                                        inner join paket p on ls.pkt_id=p.pkt_id and ls.lls_status=1
                                                                        inner join (select max(e.eva_versi) as mev, e.lls_id from  evaluasi e inner join lelang_seleksi ls on e.lls_id=ls.lls_id where ls.lls_status=1 group by e.lls_id) me on ls.lls_id=me.lls_id
                                                                        inner join evaluasi e on me.lls_id=e.lls_id AND e.eva_jenis = 4::numeric and e.eva_versi=me.mev
                                                                        /*inner join workflow w on e.eva_wf_id = w.wf_id AND w.wf_state = 5::numeric */
                                                                        inner join nilai_evaluasi n on e.eva_id = n.eva_id AND n.nev_lulus = 1::numeric
                                                                        left join (select   ls.lls_id,      
                                                    CASE
                                                        WHEN (select count(*) from jadwal j where now() BETWEEN j.dtj_tglawal and j.dtj_tglakhir and j.lls_id=ls.lls_id) > 0 THEN '0'::numeric
                                                        ELSE '1'::numeric
                                                     END 
                                                      AS s_selesai
                                                from lelang_seleksi ls order by ls.lls_id desc) tahapan on tahapan.lls_id=ls.lls_id
                                                                        where ls.lls_status=1 and tahapan.s_selesai=1) pemenang on e.lls_id=pemenang.lls_id and n.psr_id=pemenang.psr_id
                                            where e.lls_id=pemenang.lls_id and n.psr_id=pemenang.psr_id
                                            group by e.lls_id,n.psr_id,pemenang.pagu_selesai,pemenang.nev_harga,pemenang.eva_jenis
                                            )selesailelang on semualelang.lls_id=selesailelang.lls_id
group by date_part('YEAR', semualelang.lls_tgl_setuju)) dt
on cast(thn.tahun as double precision)=dt.tahun_lelang
ORDER BY thn.tahun ASC
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: With that degree of JOINs/complexity, someone would have to be on-site to help. Ask your DBA or invest in a good DBA consultant.

Comment: not everyone can speak Indonesian bro

Answer (score 0):

you can speed up your query speed like this with [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) ,

1. generalize all your query to get some pattern
2. create database view
3. re-write all your query
4. i.e -- a) make a view with this ->

   SELECT agen.agc_nama,sk.stk_id,sk.stk_nama,ls.lls_id,ls.pkt_id,sd.sbd_id,sd.sbd_ket,a.ang_tahun,p.pkt_nama,p.pkt_pagu,p.pkt_hps,p.kgr_id,ls.mtd_pemilihan,ls.lls_tgl_setuju FROM lelang_seleksi ls 
           LEFT JOIN paket p ON ls.pkt_id=p.pkt_id
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT pa.pkt_id,pa.ang_id FROM paket_anggaran pa INNER JOIN (SELECT pkt_id,MAX(auditupdate) AS auditupdate FROM paket_anggaran GROUP BY pkt_id) pa1 ON pa1.pkt_id=pa.pkt_id AND pa1.auditupdate=pa.auditupdate) pa ON pa.pkt_id=p.pkt_id
           LEFT JOIN satuan_kerja sk ON p.stk_id=sk.stk_id
           LEFT JOIN agency agen ON agen.agc_id=sk.agc_id
           LEFT JOIN anggaran a ON pa.ang_id=a.ang_id
           LEFT JOIN sumber_dana sd ON a.sbd_id=sd.sbd_id
           WHERE ls.lls_status=1

b) then make a view with this -

```
SELECT e.lls_id,n.psr_id,pemenang.pagu_selesai,pemenang.nev_harga,MIN(n.nev_harga) AS penawaran,pemenang.eva_jenis FROM evaluasi e INNER JOIN nilai_evaluasi n ON e.eva_id=n.eva_id 
                                                INNER JOIN (SELECT n.psr_id,e.eva_id,ls.lls_id, p.pkt_pagu AS pagu_selesai, n.nev_harga,e.eva_jenis FROM lelang_seleksi ls
                                                                        INNER JOIN paket p ON ls.pkt_id=p.pkt_id AND ls.lls_status=1
                                                                        INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(e.eva_versi) AS mev, e.lls_id FROM  evaluasi e INNER JOIN lelang_seleksi ls ON e.lls_id=ls.lls_id WHERE ls.lls_status=1 GROUP BY e.lls_id) me ON ls.lls_id=me.lls_id
                                                                        INNER JOIN evaluasi e ON me.lls_id=e.lls_id AND e.eva_jenis = 4::NUMERIC AND e.eva_versi=me.mev
                                                                        /*inner join workflow w on e.eva_wf_id = w.wf_id AND w.wf_state = 5::numeric */
                                                                        INNER JOIN nilai_evaluasi n ON e.eva_id = n.eva_id AND n.nev_lulus = 1::NUMERIC
                                                                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   ls.lls_id,      
                                                    CASE
                                                        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jadwal j WHERE NOW() BETWEEN j.dtj_tglawal AND j.dtj_tglakhir AND j.lls_id=ls.lls_id) > 0 THEN '0'::NUMERIC
                                                        ELSE '1'::NUMERIC
                                                     END 
                                                      AS s_selesai
                                                FROM lelang_seleksi ls ORDER BY ls.lls_id DESC) tahapan ON tahapan.lls_id=ls.lls_id
                                                                        WHERE ls.lls_status=1 AND tahapan.s_selesai=1) pemenang ON e.lls_id=pemenang.lls_id AND n.psr_id=pemenang.psr_id
                                            WHERE e.lls_id=pemenang.lls_id AND n.psr_id=pemenang.psr_id
                                            GROUP BY e.lls_id,n.psr_id,pemenang.pagu_selesai,pemenang.nev_harga,pemenang.eva_jenis
```

c) then make a view with this -

```
SELECT
    COUNT(semualelang)                      AS total_paket,
    COUNT(selesailelang)                        AS total_paket_selesai,
    SUM(semualelang.pkt_pagu)                   AS total_pagu,
    SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai)                 AS pagu_selesai,
    SUM(selesailelang.penawaran)                    AS penawaran,
    SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai) - SUM(selesailelang.penawaran)  AS selisih,
    ROUND((SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai) - SUM(selesailelang.penawaran)) / SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai)  * 100::NUMERIC)   AS selisih_persen,
    date_part('YEAR', semualelang.lls_tgl_setuju)                   AS tahun_lelang
FROM() semualelang 
   LEFT JOIN ()selesailelang ON semualelang.lls_id=selesailelang.lls_id
GROUP BY date_part('YEAR', semualelang.lls_tgl_setuju)
```

actually this shouuld look like this -->

```
SELECT
    COUNT(semualelang)                      AS total_paket,
    COUNT(selesailelang)                        AS total_paket_selesai,
    SUM(semualelang.pkt_pagu)                   AS total_pagu,
    SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai)                 AS pagu_selesai,
    SUM(selesailelang.penawaran)                    AS penawaran,
    SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai) - SUM(selesailelang.penawaran)  AS selisih,
    ROUND((SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai) - SUM(selesailelang.penawaran)) / SUM(selesailelang.pagu_selesai)  * 100::NUMERIC)   AS selisih_persen,
    date_part('YEAR', semualelang.lls_tgl_setuju)                   AS tahun_lelang
FROM semualelang_view 
     LEFT JOIN selesailelang_view ON semualelang_view.lls_id=selesailelang_view.lls_id
GROUP BY date_part('YEAR', semualelang_view.lls_tgl_setuju)
```

THIS IS NOT SUPPOSED TO BE CORRECT CODE - YOU HAVE TO FIND YOUR WAY OWN, THIS IS JUST PSEDUO FLOW HOW YOU CAN ACHIEVE YOUR GOAL.